# Storyboard xib live view renders all subviews in top-left corner

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, xib

I am using XCode 12.1 and I am trying to create some reusable XIBs and want to render them in the storyboard. My problem is that all those views will be rendered in the top-left corner, just like if the frame of my loaded view is `CGRect.zero`. The view controller in the storyboard looks like this:

[image: Preview in storyboard]

I have made a subclass of `UIView` that dynamically loads a view from `.xib`:

```swift
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class NibView: UIView {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        self.createNibView()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.createNibView()
    }
    
    private func createNibView() {
        guard let view = loadFromNib() else { return }
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(view)
        self.createConstraints(for: view)
        self.setNeedsLayout()
    }
    
    private func loadFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
        view?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }
    
    private func createConstraints(for view: UIView) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

}
```

and a subclass of this view:

```swift
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RDTextField: NibView {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorIcon: UIImageView!
}
```

with the associated xib:

[image: Xib]

In storyboard, I have added a view for which I've set the class of this custom view, which is the selected view from the image with the storyboard.

I have also tried playing with `awakeAfter(using coder:)` with no better results, I tried to use the autoresizing mask, which is slightly better, in the sense that it sets the origin correctly, but it does not have the correct size. Anyway, I would like to use `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` disabled and use my own constraints.

I have also tried to debug these views, but XCode won't attach to any process and I cannot find the logs inside the `Console.app`.

Note: I have an `IBDesignable` extension for `UIView` which helps me setting border color, width and radius. I have tried to disable it, but without any results.

Note 2: At runtime everything works properly, but live view in storyboard is pretty much needed as well.

Did anyone encounter this or have any idea how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **root** view of a Storyboard object always uses an Autoresizing Mask. Your code is disabling that.

Remove one line from your `createNibView()` func in your `NibView` class

```
private func createNibView() {
    guard let view = loadFromNib() else { return }
    
    // don't do this!
    //self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    self.addSubview(view)
    self.createConstraints(for: view)
    self.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thank you, sir! This worked just fine and you ended my 2 days of nightmare. I have indeed tried to use the autoresizing masks, but maybe I had other problems there that made it not work. Just out of curiosity: will this in fact generate 2 sets of constraints at runtime?

Comment: @VladRusu - you don't need to even think about autoresizing masks. Use normal auto-layout constraints for all of your XIB's subviews, and treat the `RDTextField` that you added in Storyboard just like any other view that you add in Storyboard.